# spec.clusterIP: Invalid value: "": field is immutable

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

We have Helm 3.0.3 and 1.18 k8s and since one year we did not face any issue like as below before. We deploy several microservices via helm to k8s and all works fine so far. But even if we did not change anything for service field we are receiving error like as below.

Here is my command how I deploy to k8s. When I uninstall the service in k8s and start re-build it works ok but when I need to push new changes ı again face this error.

```
+ helm upgrade --install --debug --force xx-ui-dev --values values.dev.yaml --namespace dev --set image.tag=608 .
```

---

Error

```
history.go:52: [debug] getting history for release xx-ui-dev
upgrade.go:120: [debug] preparing upgrade for xx-ui-dev
upgrade.go:128: [debug] performing update for xx-ui-dev
upgrade.go:292: [debug] creating upgraded release for xx-ui-dev
client.go:173: [debug] checking 7 resources for changes
client.go:432: [debug] Replaced "xx-ui-dev" with kind NetworkPolicy for kind NetworkPolicy

client.go:432: [debug] Replaced "xx-ui-dev" with kind ServiceAccount for kind ServiceAccount

client.go:432: [debug] Replaced "xx-ui-dev-auth" with kind Secret for kind Secret

client.go:432: [debug] Replaced "xx-ui-dev-config" with kind ConfigMap for kind ConfigMap

client.go:205: [debug] error updating the resource "xx-ui-dev":
     failed to replace object: Service "xx-ui-dev" is invalid: spec.clusterIP: Invalid value: "": field is immutable
client.go:432: [debug] Replaced "xx-ui-dev" with kind Deployment for kind Deployment

client.go:432: [debug] Replaced "xx-ui-dev" with kind HorizontalPodAutoscaler for kind HorizontalPodAutoscaler

upgrade.go:351: [debug] warning: Upgrade "xx-ui-dev" failed: failed to replace object: Service "xx-ui-dev" is invalid: spec.clusterIP: Invalid value: "": field is immutable
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: failed to replace object: Service "xx-ui-dev" is invalid: spec.clusterIP: Invalid value: "": field is immutable
helm.go:84: [debug] failed to replace object: Service "xx-ui-dev" is invalid: spec.clusterIP: Invalid value: "": field is immutable
```

---

service.yaml

```
    spec:
      type: {{ .Values.service.type }}
      ports:
        - port: {{ .Values.service.port }}
          targetPort: 50003
          protocol: TCP
          name: http
      selector:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "xx-ui.name" . }}
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
        tier: backend
```

---

```
values.dev.yaml

   service:
     type: ClusterIP
     port: 80
```

Comment: You can find related information from [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/798)

Comment: so should I remove the --force flag ? Am I correct ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using `--force` with `helm upgrade`, helm is using replace strategy instead of patch.

Have a look at the following [helm code](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/pkg/kube/client.go#L423-L450):

```
if force {
    var err error
    obj, err = helper.Replace(target.Namespace, target.Name, true, target.Object)
        
    ...

} else {
    patch, patchType, err := createPatch(target, currentObj)

    ...

    // send patch to server
    obj, err = helper.Patch(target.Namespace, target.Name, patchType, patch, nil)
}
```

Replace strategy is causing the errors you see.
Have a look at [this kubectl issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/798) if you are wondering why this happens.

Answer (score 3):

@matt is correct **`--force`** use replacement strategy.

I have recently faced this issue while updating the service selectors using helm, so as a quick fix/hack I directly edit the service and make the desired changes(update the selectors), and then run the helm command to sync(helm upgrade --force *release_name*).

It will not show any change in the service. (Pure hack but helpful)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue the other day (for my sins, I had to do some Helm but it was actually enjoyable!)

If you are trying to change the service and don't mind  keeping the cluster IP address it has then you can do something simple like:

```
{{$existingService := (lookup "v1" "Service" $.Values.environment.namespace $.Values.myservice.name) }}
  ..
  {{ if $existingService }}
  clusterIP: {{$existingService.spec.clusterIP}}
  {{end}}
```

(remove spaces if you want)

That is, fill in the service with the old IP address if it's there already.

Hope this helps somebody

Andy